# On target answer, deleted two years after. Why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I would like someone to look into this answer. It had 9 upvotes, 2 downvotes, then mysteriously received 12 more downvotes and was deleted two years later.

It is a very good, on point on answer. I really really want to know WHY it was deleted, and if the downvotes look suspicious, because I have been targetted by downvote posses on Stack Overflow in the past.

Question:   [Best way to connect to mysql with php securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710511/best-way-to-connect-to-mysql-with-php-securely)
Answer:     https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3710674/revisions

I believe this question got caught up in the Reddit Codeathlon Downvote Event which was previously acknowledged here on Meta. This post was deleted on Sep 10, and the posse was discovered on Sep 12, 2012.

- [A solid, real question of mine w/ 18 up votes, 4 stars was removed. And I can't figure out why :-/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155824/a-solid-real-question-of-mine-w-18-up-votes-4-stars-was-removed-and-i-cant)
- [Policy on reputation abuse from vindictive redditor trolls?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146985/policy-on-reputation-abuse-from-vindictive-redditor-trolls)

Comment: Oh boy. if it's related to that reddit codeathlon thing, several STackOverflow members were chastised, warned, temp banned, etc. for forming a downvote brigade specifically against me.

Comment: I have a side question... How come my meta.stackoverflow.com question asked in Sep 2012 that found and discovered the downvote posse is also missing?? It says I've only asked 1 question ever here, but that is certainly wrong.

Comment: There are deleted comments, but they don't explain anything.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Your old meta questions are probably on the network-wide http://meta.stackexchange.com which spun off from meta.stackoverflow.com earlier this year.

Comment: OK I have edited the post with the two relevant Meta questions. I think I just missed this question when they were restoring my account circa Sep 2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your answer was flagged because it contained 'terse remarks'. The moderator edited your answer to remove the disputed remarks [((that don't bear repeating here, but I'll link to them) with the heading "F***ing downvoters")](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3710674/3)

You then edited some of it back in (in the form of 'Are you cowards'?).

[No doubt this set off the people in that chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5320615#5320615), who then mob downvoted it and deleted it once it hit a negative score.

That's my guess at least.

Moral of the story: Don't call people names.

While it may be linked to the questions you edited into your meta question; my general advice would be to not engage, and certainly don't edit abusive comments or expletives into your post because of downvotes.

Take the high road, and that way when someone does something unfair, there's no possible defense they have.  In this situation, they could say that your comments were abusive, and they'd be correct.

Comment: Sage advice well heeded. Thank you for your research and clarification. I accept the consequences of allowing myself to feel victimized and lash out.

Comment: I'd also like to thank the StackExchange community for being so professional on the whole. It's the primary reason I still contribute and engage here.